# select box that would be populated through a web api

Tags: windows-phone-8, asp.net-web-api

I am developing a windows mobile app. But I am currently stocked at one of my task. Which is to create a select box that would get populated with Continents round the world from my web api. My first problem is I have not seen the select box control in windows phone 8 toolkit. So I don't know how to create a select box. I also need help with populating the select box when the users lands on the page. Cos the user is expected to select his or her continent.

When I put this in my xaml I get an error saying toolkit prefix is undefined

```
  <toolkit:ListPicker 
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                x:Name="KListPicker"
                Header="K"               
                ListPickerMode="Normal"
                >

                <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="K 1" />
                <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="K 2" />
                <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="K 3" />
                <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="K 4" />
                <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="K 5" />
            </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a listpicker(acts like a combobox/selectbox).

Listpicker is actually the Windows Phone 7 equivalent of the ComboBox control. It shows the selected item  from a list and also allows the user to pick from a list if they want to change it. ListPicker is a standard ItemsControl subclass with all the common elements of a Selector, set of properties for customization and item display, data binding support.

you just need to learn how to make a listpicker and how to bind data inside it

[here](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/listpicker-for-wp7-in-depth) is the best link to take a start with.

Adding a reference to microsoft.phone.controls.toolit dll

just look for the line `shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"` on your xaml and add a line above that

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

Comment: Thanks but it is throwing error in my project. maybe cause I setting it to windows 8 by default.

Comment: that really doesn't matter, just share with the code you are making for that, and the error you are getting

Comment: Ok Bro. I pasted the Listpicker in my grid but the xaml editor complained about not recognizing the toolkit package. It says toolkit prefix is undefined

Comment: Check my post again I have edited and pasted the code. thanks for your perusal

Comment: Okay I am assuming that you have the toolkit dll(microsoft.phone.controls.toolkit) referred in your solution. You just need to declare the dll on the top of the xaml page. Just check the edits made in the answer.

Comment: Sorry I am using coding4funToolkit Maybe I should go and install the microsoft toolkit

Comment: I just installed the microsoft tool kit and it works like magic

Comment: Do you think I should uninstall the coding4Fun toolkit since I have the microsoft toolkit

Comment: yes, Microsoft toolkit is a vast one, Coding for fun is merely a subset of that. remove it if you are no more requiring it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this Thread will help you

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/11/03/listpicker-i-hardly-even-know-er-a-detailed-overview-of-the-windows-phone-toolkit-s-listpicker-control.aspx

Comment: I tried the list picker in my xaml. but it is displaying an error message. It is not working for me. Maybe because I specified my project to target windows 8. Since it is a windows 7 control. It showing errors

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 <TextBlock
                x:Name="title"
                Text="School" 
                    Foreground="Black"
                    FontSize="32"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"

                Margin="5,32,5,23" 
                Tap="title_Tap_1"
                Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}" Height="52" >

              <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu >
                                <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                                    <toolkit:MenuItem Header ="School" Click="MenuItem_School"/>
                                    <toolkit:MenuItem Header ="Class"  Click="MenuItem_Class"/>
                                    <toolkit:MenuItem Header ="Me"     Click="MenuItem_Me"/>
                                </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                            </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    </TextBlock>
```